# How would I prove $x^2 \ge x $ for integral $x$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-verification, integers

As the title says, how would I simply prove $x^2 \ge x$ for integral $x$?

Should it not already be assumed that a number multiplied by itself is simply larger or equal to the existing number it was multiplied by based upon **integer values** only.

I only get as far as knowing $x^2 \ge 0$ but I am unsure where to proceed from this point.

Comment: Hint: divide by x. You'll need to branch, but both branches will end up true

Comment: @DonAntonio it's for integers.

Comment: What should be assumed is if b>0.  And x \le  y.  Then bx \le  by.  So if x >= 1 then.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x \le 0 \implies x^2 \ge 0 \ge x \implies x^2 \ge x$, if $x > 0 \implies x \ge 1$ since its an integer. So $x^2 -x = x(x-1) \ge 0$ since $x \ge 0, x - 1\ge 0$. So $x^2 \ge x$.

Comment: Why can you assume $ x<=0 $ ?

Comment: Oh ok, can any assumption be made for mathematical proofs if reasonable? I've just started doing these so sorry if the questions seem newbie.

Comment: He didn't assume x <=0. He knew either x <= 0 OR x > 0. So he did both cases separately. If x <=0 then he got the result. If x > 0 he got the result. Either way he got the result so it is true.

Comment: He actually did the exact *opposite* of assuming. As he *couldn't* assume x > 0.  He had to do do that as a separate case.

Comment: Oh yes, I see how the cases were split now and eventually compounded at the end for the proof. Thank you for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

It is sufficient to show for natural $x$. But $x \ge 1$ so $x^2 \ge 1\cdot x = x$.(or am I using something bad?)